# How to Make Your bot send animated messages (Like Hack Command of dank memer)

Tags: animation, discord.py

Hy everyone.I Have been writing a code in which the bot sends an animated message by editing it quickly(like hack command of dank memer).Here's the code but unfortunately its not responding to it
and says 'Cannot edit a message authored by another user'

Here's The Code

```
     async def virus(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None, *, virus: str = "trojan"):
      user54 = user or ctx.author
      list = (
          f"``[▓▓▓                    ] / {virus}-virus.exe Packing files.``",
          f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓                ] - {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
          f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓           ] \ {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
          f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓         ] | {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
          f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓      ] / {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
          f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓   ] - {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
          f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ ] \ {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
          f"``Successfully downloaded {virus}-virus.exe``",
          "``Injecting virus.   |``",
          "``Injecting virus..  /``",
          "``Injecting virus... -``",
          f"``Successfully Injected {virus}-virus.exe into {user54.name}``",
      )
      for i in list:
          await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
          await ctx.message.edit(content=i)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the error, you cannot edit another users message, `ctx.message` is referring to the message the command was invoked with. You need to send a message first, then edit it.

This should work:

```py
    async def virus(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None, *, virus: str = "trojan"):
        user54 = user or ctx.author
        initial_message = await ctx.send(f"``[▓                    ] / {virus}-virus.exe Packing files.``")
        list = (
            f"``[▓▓▓                    ] / {virus}-virus.exe Packing files.``",
            f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓                ] - {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
            f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓           ] \ {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
            f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓         ] | {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
            f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓      ] / {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
            f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓   ] - {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
            f"``[▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ ] \ {virus}-virus.exe Packing files..``",
            f"``Successfully downloaded {virus}-virus.exe``",
            "``Injecting virus.   |``",
            "``Injecting virus..  /``",
            "``Injecting virus... -``",
            f"``Successfully Injected {virus}-virus.exe into {user54.name}``",
            )
        for i in list:
            await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
            await initial_message.edit(content=i)
```

Comment: tysm i have been looking for solution for quite some time